# how do I make the program take the input before displaying results

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I made this program, the problem I'm asking the user to input their age and name then the program should use the input to print the statement. however the when I type the age then press enter the program executes all the statements without waiting for me to enter my name.. how can I fix this?

```
    Scanner input =     new Scanner(System.in);
    int age;
    String name;

    System.out.println("Please enter your age ");
    age = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("and now enter your name");
    name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Your name is " +name + " and you're " +age + "years old");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nextLine()` for both:

```
System.out.println("Please enter your age ");
age = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
System.out.println("and now enter your name");
name = input.nextLine();
```

The problem is that when you hit `Enter` after you input the age, the resulting newline is interpreted as the end of the input for the following `nextLine().`

You could also use `next()` instead of `nextLine()`, but then `John Doe` would be interpreted as just `John` because `next()` uses whitespace as a separator.

Comment: I just tried and I got a type mismatch exception when I tried to use nextLine for the age variable

Comment: @maya91 You have to use it with `Integer.parseInt(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use next() instead of nextLine() at *name* variable.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int age;
        String name;

        System.out.println("Please enter your age ");
        age = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("and now enter your name");
        name = input.next();

        System.out.println("Your name is " +name + " and you're " +age + " years old");
    }
```